# Airflow Executing every 57 seconds, irrespective of schedule interval

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have created a simple Airflow DAG, which I have scheduled to be trigger every 5 minutes. However, in actuality, it gets triggered every 57 seconds.

I have tried setting the schedule using both:

- a CRON schedule expression string
- A datetime timedelta object

And still get the same result for both versions.

I have also attempted different schedule intervals, and the result is always the same. It gets triggered every 57 seconds.

I would like to know why it gets triggered every 57 seconds, instead of the interval i specify, and how do I fix it.

## Code

Here is the code I use to create my dag, placed in the `~/airflow/dags` directory. The task simply prints out a message with a timestamp to a log file.

```py
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

# DEFAULT ARGUMENTS TO PASS TO EACH OPERATOR
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    }

dag = DAG(
    'mydag2',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A sample DAG',
    schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *",
    # schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5),
    )

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_message',
    bash_command=f'echo "{datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}  tick" >> ~/logs/log.log',
    dag=dag,
    )
```

## Results

Looking at the log file, it shows that the command is being executed every 57 seconds.

```
2020-10-25 01:30:17  tick
2020-10-25 01:31:14  tick
2020-10-25 01:32:11  tick
2020-10-25 01:33:08  tick
2020-10-25 01:34:06  tick
2020-10-25 01:35:03  tick
2020-10-25 01:36:00  tick
2020-10-25 01:36:57  tick
2020-10-25 01:37:54  tick
2020-10-25 01:38:51  tick
```

But looking at the DAG runs, on the webapp, it says that they were executed every 5 minutes but several days before now (even though new entries appear every 57 seconds)

[image: screenshot of webapp]

## Context

I use the following version:

- Airflow 1.10.12
- Ubuntu 20.04
- python 3.8.5

Comment: Have you tried playing with `'start_date': days_ago(2),`? This likely isn't the case because it wouldn't explain the 57 second thing, but if catch up by default is enabled on your cluster airflow would attempt to backfill runs for the last two days. https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-airflow-tips-and-best-practices-ff64ce92ef8 explains some of this

Answer (score 0):

It is because of [catchup_by_default](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-run.html#catchup) property of DAG. By default, upon creation, it will start batches first batch as `start_date + schedule interval` and then will iterate for batch based on `schedule interval`. Since this is catch up, it would try to complete all runs as soon as possible (Only `max_active_runs` limiting the number of batches running at any given time).

In your DAG, start date is `days_ago(2)` so it is trying to catchup for all batches between start date and now. That is why you see entry for each execution date.

If you do not want it to run for past batches, you can set `catchup` as `False`